# How to perform a Timer class with javafx with javafx Object changes inside

Tags: java, javafx

I've tried to make FXML Label to refresh by itself in certain time intervals,
but i got an exeption shown underneath.

My attempt here:

```java
 public static void showActualViewer(MixerChannel mixerChannel, Label label){
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        label.setText("Actual Viewers : " + mixerChannel.viewersCurrent);
                        System.out.println("works");

                    }

                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

ERROR:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0

Comment: Are you mixing `JavaFX` and `AWT`?

Comment: yes i did there is something wrong with it ?  :)

Comment: It is something you should not be doing unless you 100% have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *setting* the event handler in the java fx thread with Platform.runLater(); however, code in the actionPerformed() method will run on the *Event* thread. To go around this, surround the code in actionPerformed() with the Platform.runLater()

hope that helps!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :D